# PLSQL Loop taking lot of time to execute

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a Oracle procedure which is updating below 10,000 records. if I run the normal SQL statement, it is returning the result immediately with in seconds(30).
same statment in procedure loop it is going to endlessly.

My loop statment below.
Note: data FIELD Data type is a clob not varchar2.

statment:

```
select
  'LB_COPY_CHANGE-'||8  LAST_MODIFIED_BY, 
  rec.COR_ID_old,
  rec.COR_ID_NEW,
  replace(replace(replace(a.data,'''id''&#x3a;'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||',','''id''&#x3a;'||rec.COR_ID_NEW||','),'&#x27;id&#x27;&#x3a;'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||',','&#x27;id&#x27;&#x3a;'||rec.COR_ID_NEW||','),'''id'':'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||',','''id'':'||rec.COR_ID_NEW||',') as data 
from KPI_MET_FIELD_DATA a, CUSTOM_TEMP_TABLE_SESSION_1 rec 
where A.cmf_fk_id in (145,146,147) 
    and TYPE_LB in (14,15,16) 
    and  a.KDB_FK_ID in (
       select distinct km.KDB_FK_ID 
       from KPI_MET_FIELD_DATA km , KPI_DET_BASE kp, KPI_REL_KPI_SCORECARD ksc, STR_DET_EMP_SCORECARD sc 
       where ksc.SDE_FK_ID=sc.SDE_PK_ID 
           and km.KDB_FK_ID = ksc.KDB_KPI_FK_ID 
           and km.is_deleted=0 
           and kp.kdb_pk_id = km.KDB_FK_ID 
           and kp.is_deleted=0 
           and km.cmf_fk_id in (145,146,147) 
           and sc.sdp_fk_id = 8) 
     and a.is_deleted=0 
     and (a.data like '%'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||'%');


FOR rec in (SELECT * FROM CUSTOM_TEMP_TABLE_SESSION where TYPE_LB in (14,15,16)) LOOP 
   update KPI_MET_FIELD_DATA 
      set LAST_MODIFIED_BY='LB_COPY_CHANGE-'||p2 , 
      data = replace(replace(replace(data,'''id''&#x3a;'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||',','''id''&#x3a;'||rec.COR_ID_NEW||','),'&#x27;id&#x27;&#x3a;'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||',','&#x27;id&#x27;&#x3a;'||rec.COR_ID_NEW||','),'''id'':'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||',','''id'':'||rec.COR_ID_NEW||',') 
   where cmf_fk_id in (145,146,147) 
       and KDB_FK_ID in (
          select distinct km.KDB_FK_ID 
          from KPI_MET_FIELD_DATA km , KPI_DET_BASE kp, KPI_REL_KPI_SCORECARD ksc, STR_DET_EMP_SCORECARD sc 
          where ksc.SDE_FK_ID=sc.SDE_PK_ID 
              and km.KDB_FK_ID = ksc.KDB_KPI_FK_ID 
              and km.is_deleted=0 
              and kp.kdb_pk_id = km.KDB_FK_ID 
              and kp.is_deleted=0 
              and km.cmf_fk_id in (145,146,147) 
              and sc.sdp_fk_id = p2) 
       and is_deleted=0 ;
```

Comment: What do you mean, "normal SQL statement?"  Without providing more detail, like an explain plan, there could be many possible reasons.  Need more details.  Why do you even need a loop?

Comment: select statement for same result set  :

Comment: Is there any cause to update the same records several times in loop? In *WHERE* statement you have the filters which isn't changed during the *LOOP* statement. It means that you update the same record once and once again

Comment: A select is different than an update, and does two very different things.  Run an explain plan on the update.

Comment: In the update from the FOR loop you are missing a where filter line "and (a.data like '%'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||'%')" which causes the update to run for each record returned by the FOR LOOP cursor. So the UPDATE does a cartesian product with the FOR LOOP cursor while in the select there is a JOIN between the two.

Answer (score 1):

There are several weaknesses in your code.

- `WHERE KDB_FK_ID in (select distinct ...` does not make any sense. There is no need to make `DISTINCT` for an `IN ()` clause.
- Use ANSI join syntax instead of old Oracle join syntax, it is less error-prone

But the main difference is, your loop does not contain join condition `(a.data like '%'||rec.COR_ID_OLD||'%')`, i.e. you update **entire** table `KPI_MET_FIELD_DATA` again and again for each row in `CUSTOM_TEMP_TABLE_SESSION where TYPE_LB in (14,15,16)`

Comment: yes sir, agree with you but is there any alternative solutions because already changed what you found out previous comments accordingly. but still same result. Thank's

Comment: Again, the the statements are doing different things - how do you expect them to run the same time of execution?